# Debug mode not working as expected in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am running into a strange issue when trying to add 404 pages to my application.

I have two separate folders that I use for different configurations, one for my local environment and one for production.

So, when I change my `"debug" => true` in my local configuration, I get a Whoops! as I expect.  Changing that option to `false` shows me a general error message, which I would also expect.

The problem comes about when I try to edit that general error message.  The documentation states to add something like this into your app (which I have done):

```
App::missing(function() {
    return "Not found!";
});
```

What happens is no matter if my local environment's `debug` is set to `true` or `false` it will always return that message if that code is placed within my application.  I want to be able to see a Whoops! on my local environment but on production they should receive a general error message.

Am I doing something wrong here?  How can I receive a Whoops! screen to track down bugs locally but send a 404 message in production??

Answer (score 1):

Detect your environment first and then setup the error you want to show on that env

```
if (App::environment('local'))
{
    App::missing(function() {
        return "Not found!";
    });
}
```

Comment: Seems like a verbose solution for something Laravel already knows.

Comment: At least it looks like a solution.

Comment: You will have to check your environment variable.